# I can not seem to get a while loop to work with my code

Tags: javascript, while-loop

When I put the while loop in like this, my background and my prompts never show up. I have no clue on why would be causing this. Everything else works to perfection, it is just once I add the while loop my code breaks. I have tried a for loop as well but it also does not work.

```
//score
 
var score = 0

//replay loop

var replay = "yes"

//name of each gen 1 pokemon

var pname = ['#']

//images for each one
var bg = ['#']

while (replay == 'yes'){ 

background = bg[num = Math.floor(Math.random() * bg.length)];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + background + ')';

setTimeout(() => {   
    
  var answer = prompt("What pokemon is this?")
  
   if (answer.toLowerCase() == pname[num].toLowerCase()) {
    alert("correct")
    score ++
    replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
  } else {
    alert("incorrect")
    replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
  }

}, 2000);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e6cbt2dz/

Comment: Your while should say `while (replay == "yes" )` instead of `replay = "yes"`

Comment: It still does not work :( thanks though :D

Comment: `var pname = [#]` this isn't valid syntax, there should be a string or something inside.

Comment: `var bg = [#],` same thing here but you also have a trailing comma which shouldn't be there / should be a semi colon `;`

Comment: Syntax issues aside, this while loop is going to change the background as fast as your browser can do it and set many thousands of timeouts. I’m guessing that is not your actual intent.

Comment: Well, you are **setting** timeouts in that _while_ loop.  But they won't execute until 2000 ms later.  That's like ordering a pizza and then every time you hang up the phone ordering another pizza.  Nothing in that loop changes the value of 'replay'.  The 'replay' doesn't get changed until the timeout happens...which is like when your pizza arrives, if you know what I mean.  Before the timeout occurs, you are frantically and infinitely setting more timeouts in a tight loop where the condition is not changing.

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout function is going to take 2 seconds before it runs, thus causing your while loop to execute an actual massive number of times in 2 seconds... all the time updating the background image (which it probably does easily over 10,000 X in 2 seconds.

I suggest using recursion:

```
//score
 
var score = 0;

//replay loop

var replay = "yes";

//name of each gen 1 pokemon

// var pname = [#]; <- this needs to hold all the available names

//images for each one
//var bg = [#]; <-this needs to hold all the available images
let keepPlaying = function(){
  background = bg[Math.floor(Math.random() * bg.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + background + ')';
  
  var answer = prompt("What pokemon is this?")
  
   if (answer.toLowerCase == pname[num].toLowerCase) {
    alert("correct")
    score ++
    replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
  } else {
    alert("incorrect")
    replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
  }
  if(replay == 'yes')
    keepPlaying()
  else
    return(score)
}()
```

Comment: I deleted everything below the second array and put this in, the the same problem happens. Where it is just a white screen and nothing is loading.

Comment: Sorry... Did you make an initial call to keepPlaying()

Comment: its ok, also I have no clue what you are asking? Sorry I am very bad at understand coding terms. :(

Comment: I changed the answer to make an initial call by adding "()" at the end

Comment: Ok it does not work, I understand what you are saying now XD

Comment: Oh, i see there was a syntax error in this statement "var bg = [#],".  I updated the answer to include everything

Comment: I am sorry to report it still does not work.

Comment: OK, I'll try one more time.  I've updated the answer to be pure Javascript to replace react syntax.  If this doesn't work, then hit F12 on your browser, then click on Console tab, and report what error it shows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237739/discussion-between-joseph-troy-and-sprat).

Comment: 2x Failed to load recourse: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
1x Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpended token '('

Comment: I fixed up some minor errors and got rid of the () at the end, so there are no errors but it still does not work

Comment: I changed it one last time because I found that arrow functions cannot be self-invoked.  Please take note that bg[] and pname[] must be set somewhere or the image will never display and the answer will always be incorrect.

Comment: The image loads after the text, meaning you can not see what pokemon it is. and the if statement does not do anything, like no alerts or prompts.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will not wait for setTimeout() to complete .You need to find out a different way.

This both line are not valid

```
var pname = [#] // var pname = ['#']
var bg = [#],   // var bg = ['#']
```

```js
var score = 0
var replay = "yes"
var pname = ['#']
var bg = ['#']

var index = 0;
(function asyncLoop() {
  background = bg[num = Math.floor(Math.random() * bg.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + background + ')';
  setTimeout(function() {
     var answer = prompt("What pokemon is this?")
     if (answer == pname[num]) {
      alert("correct")
      score ++
      replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
    } else {
      alert("incorrect")
      replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
    }
    if (replay == 'yes'){
       asyncLoop();
    } 
     
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: Thanks this works really well, where would I add something that would when they dont want to replay. Tells them a goodbye message and a score? would that be out side of the loop?

Comment: ` if (replay == 'yes'){
       asyncLoop();
    }else{
      //here you can write the goodbye message and a score
    }`

Comment: You welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let me point out a few things in the code first.

var pname = [#] --> is not a valid syntax

var bg = [#], --> not valid and having a comma here

Also the setTimeOut function is getting executed many times hence making the script unresponsive.

Give this a try :

- I have excluded the image section from the code, which you can add later and try.

---

```
var pname = ['qq','ww','ee'];
   
var replay = "yes";

var score = 0;

var bg = [];

var num = 1;

keepPlaying();

function keepPlaying() {
  
    var answer = prompt("What pokemon is this?")
  
    if (answer == pname[num]) {
        alert("correct")
        score ++
        replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
    } 
    else {
        alert("incorrect")
        replay = prompt("Want to keep playing?")
    }
    if(replay == 'yes') {
        keepPlaying();
    }
    else {
        alert(score);
    }
}
```

Comment: The background loads after the question